# Is melodic analysis a thing?

Tags: melody, analysis

I know that harmonic analysis can be done like this:

*i iv V i*

Is there a similar standard for melodic analysis? Is melodic analysis a thing?

Thanks, Nathan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There is a whole discipline for it: http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/krr2/mel_anal.html

One looks a range, key, ornaments, type of tone connections, essential and non-essential tones, rhythm, harmonic implications, etc.

Comment: Thanks! They mostly teach harmonic analysis in music theory classes, but I'd never heard of melodic analysis.